# how to check for non-nil value of associated attribute - is there a more succinct way?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have items and they have prices in a has_one relationship. In the price object, there is a price value (unfortunately true). I'd like to be able to test for non-nil values of item.price.price. In the view, there is an `add_to_order` helper method that should show only if there is a price.price. I test using for this condition with:

```
<% if item.price && !item.price.price.nil? %>
  <%=add_to_order item %>
<% end %>
```

but it seems pretty ugly. Is there a more succinct / 'better' way of testing for this?

thx in advance

Comment: If the pattern is repeated a lot, make a helper method to do both checks.

Comment: @Chris - not a ton; more of checks for direct attributes rather than calling into a helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid logic in your views and simply have your `add_to_order` method handle the `item` validation.

```
def add_to_order(item)
  return unless price = item.price.try(:price)
  # ... your implementation
  # the items price is in the price variable for you
end
```

[Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

Your view would just become:

```
<%=add_to_order item %>
```

since all your logic would be in the `add_to_order` helper method.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It provides a cleaner way than to stick the logic in the view.

Comment: thx - I'm always mixed on the no logic in the view but agree that it makes sense here. appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides a syntax sugar for this with the [try method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
<% unless item.price.try(price).nil? %>
  <%= add_to_order item %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The logic is flipped because I am using an unless for readability. So it reads "Unless price is nil" as opposed to "If not price is nil". Just a preference on my part.

Comment: looks nice - wasn't so familiar with this syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try`. It will work safely even if item.price is nil

```
<% unless item.price.try(:price) %>
  <%=add_to_order item %>
<% end %>
```